# getStreamVolume always returns 0

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume_level = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Always returns 0 and of course real value it's not 0.

I read something about setRingerMode but I set all possible values but still returns 0.

Will someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code to get Volume value:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume_level = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, I have code just like that - i solve it, it's just problem with bad condition... :D